Mustangproject Item net price MUST equal (Gross price - Allowance amount) when gross price is provided
I try to create a XRechnung xml-file with the Mustangproject and validate it.
error is currently: Item net price MUST equal (Gross price - Allowance amount) when gross price is provided.
Path:
/rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice/rsm:SupplyChainTradeTransaction[1]/ram:IncludedSupplyChainTradeLineItem[1]/ram:SpecifiedLineTradeAgreement[1]/ram:GrossPriceProductTradePrice[1]

But i don't get how i set netprice and grossPrice, and how it affects the result.
This is the loop that processes all invoiceLines (1) already read from a JSON.
for (jsonMapper.InvoiceLine invoiceLine : invoiceData.invoiceLines) {
    String description = invoiceLine.itemInformation.itemDescription.getContent();
    String name = invoiceLine.itemInformation.itemName.getContent();
    String unit = invoiceLine.invoicedQuantityUnitOfMeasureCode.getContent();
    BigDecimal vATPercent = new BigDecimal(invoiceLine.lineVatInformation.invoicedItemVatRate.getContent());

    Double netPrice = invoiceLine.priceDetails.itemNetPrice.getContent();
    Double quantity = invoiceLine.invoicedQuantity.getContent();

    invoice.addItem(new Item(new BigDecimal(netPrice), new BigDecimal(quantity), 
            new Product(description, name, unit, vATPercent))).addAllowance(new IZUGFeRDAllowanceCharge() {

        @Override
        public BigDecimal getTotalAmount(IAbsoluteValueProvider trans) {
            return new BigDecimal(
            invoiceLine.invoiceLineAllowances.invoiceLineAllowanceAmount.getContent());
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal getTaxPercent() {
            return new BigDecimal(invoiceLine.invoiceLineAllowances.invoiceLineAllowancePercentage.getContent());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCharge() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String getReason() {
            return invoiceLine.invoiceLineAllowances.invoiceLineAllowanceReason.getContent();
        }
    });
}

Here is the XML-Part with the amounts, looks right to me
<ram:SpecifiedLineTradeAgreement>
        <ram:GrossPriceProductTradePrice>
          <ram:ChargeAmount>40.0000</ram:ChargeAmount>
          <ram:BasisQuantity unitCode="EA">1.0000</ram:BasisQuantity>
        </ram:GrossPriceProductTradePrice>
        <ram:NetPriceProductTradePrice>
          <ram:ChargeAmount>40.0000</ram:ChargeAmount>
          <ram:BasisQuantity unitCode="EA">1.0000</ram:BasisQuantity>
        </ram:NetPriceProductTradePrice>
      </ram:SpecifiedLineTradeAgreement>

______________________

<ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation>
    <ram:LineTotalAmount>400.00</ram:LineTotalAmount>
    <ram:ChargeTotalAmount>0.00</ram:ChargeTotalAmount>
    <ram:AllowanceTotalAmount>50.00</ram:AllowanceTotalAmount>
    <ram:TaxBasisTotalAmount>350.00</ram:TaxBasisTotalAmount>
    <ram:TaxTotalAmount currencyID="EUR">71.00</ram:TaxTotalAmount>
    <ram:GrandTotalAmount>421.00</ram:GrandTotalAmount>              
    <ram:TotalPrepaidAmount>0.00</ram:TotalPrepaidAmount>
    <ram:DuePayableAmount>421.00</ram:DuePayableAmount>
</ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation>

I wanted to Validate the XRechnung-XML  with https://www.epoconsulting.com/erechnung-sap/xrechnung-validator or any other validator. Error: Item net price MUST equal (Gross price - Allowance amount) when gross price is provided.

If the validation error points to an element named GrossPriceProductTradePrice we can't tell from an XML snippet not having any element of that name whether your XML is valid.

Why do you have new BigDecimal(netPrice), new BigDecimal(quantity)? You will not gain any additional precision moving from a Double to a BigDecimal. If there is precision to be lost, it is already gone.

@ElliotFrisch the XRechnung-norm gives me a Double-specification, and the Item wants a BigDecimal. If you have a better idea, please tell me, im completely new to this. Thanks

@MartinHonnen netPrice and GrossPrice are the same, but i dont know how to set them differently.

@JonasStengel That is unfortunate. My advice? Use the same pattern you did for invoicedItemVatRate. Some values can't be represented accurately as a double. For example, jshell> 0.05+0.01    $3 ==> 0.060000000000000005
